# Spring Method Parameters And Type Conversion - Performance

Tags: java, spring, performance, type-conversion, spring-rest

I'm currently working on performance tuning on my application. On my initial analysis I felt that converting **String** to **Long** manually instead of delegating that to Spring is little faster! Am I right?

i.e.,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ratesheet/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public RateSheet getRateSheet(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {

    Long longUserId = Long.valueOf(userId); // Casting manually

    // Do something here with longUserId to get RateSheet object 
    return null;
}
```

**this one faster than,**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ratesheet/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public RateSheet getRateSheet(@PathVariable("userId") Long longUserId) {
    // Spring taking care of type casting here

    // Do something here with longUserId to get RateSheet object 
    return null;
}
```

Please help me to understand the performance difference between these implementations.

Comment: Did you feel it or did you measure it... Measure always measure, don't do things because you think they are better, measure. Also don't measure ones but do a proper load/performance test (and no clicking twice isn't that).

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum actually I did a Jmeter load test. For 100 users in 10 sec ramp.. my first code is giving average latency of 660 milliseconds but the second one is giving 1.6 sec average latency.. around 40000 samples in 300 secs duration!

Comment: Maybe include that in your question as now it looks like you are asking a question based on a gut feeling and not on real measurements. You also might want to specify which spring version you are using (and first try to upgrade to the latests release of the version you are using).